# Get user information in Django templates and and checking whether it's equal to author's name

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm not able to query the username and couldn't compare to the author.
it worked for one case which is posted below.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.get_username == blog.author %}
        <a href="{% url 'update' pk=blog.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-pen fa-2x fa-spin"></i></a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
        <a href="{% url 'update' pk=blog.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-pen fa-2x fa-spin"></i></a>/
        <a href="{% url 'delete' pk=blog.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x fa-spin"></i></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

my view

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def update_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditPost(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.last_edited = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = EditPost(instance=post)
        context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blog/edit_post.html', context)
```

my model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
   last_edited = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}  by  author  {self.author}'
```

but it worked for

```
{% for comment in blog.comments.all %}
    <cite>{{ comment.author }}</cite>
    <time class="comment__time">{{ comment.created_date }}</time>
    {% if user.is_authenticated and request.user.username == comment.author %}
    <a class="reply" href="{% url 'remove' pk=comment.pk %}">remove</a>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="comment__text">
    <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

for this model is

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField()....

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.comment} by user {self.author}'
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I figured out the solution.It will be like

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated and if request.user == blog.author or if user.is_superuser %}
        <a href="{% url 'update' pk=blog.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-pen fa-2x fa-spin"></i></a>
        <a href="{% url 'delete' pk=blog.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x fa-spin"></i></a>
    {% endif %}
```

instead of

```
    {% if user.get_username == blog.author %}
        <a href="{% url 'update' pk=blog.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-pen fa-2x fa-spin"></i></a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
        <a href="{% url 'update' pk=blog.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-pen fa-2x fa-spin"></i></a>/
        <a href="{% url 'delete' pk=blog.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x fa-spin"></i></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to printout `request.__dict__` to see all data inside, and `check` what is in context.
2. What is an error message, is there any?

Comment: should i print it in view func()??